# I keep getting 0 as the value of this variable

Tags: c, calculator

I'm trying to write this program to calculate simple interest on a deposit. It's supposed to add the interest money onto the original deposit.

But it keeps making variable "rate" 0 which is why when I run it, the result is 0. Any help is appreciated.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    double d;
    double rate;
    double y;
    double final;
    int x;

    printf("Enter the deposit: ");
    scanf("%d", &d);

    printf("Enter the interest rate (0-100): ");
    scanf("%d", &rate);

    printf("Enter the number of years: ");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    rate = rate / 100;

    y = d * rate * x;

    final = d + y;


    printf("After %i number of years, the deposit in the savings account is now %d", x, rate);

}
```

Comment: You must use `"%lf"` to read double numbers.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about the obvious mistakes in your code - you do have warnings enabled, I hope ?

Comment: Also, you are printing `rate` as the answer instead of `final`. Which should be format `%f` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `double` variables you need to read them using the specifier `%lf`:

```
scanf("%lf", &d);
```

same for `rate`:

```
scanf("%lf", &rate);
```

**C99 7.19.6.2 p 11** (`fscanf`)

> `l` (ell)       (...) following a, A, e, E, `f`, F, g, or G conversion
>   specifier applies to an **argument** with type **pointer to double**;

---

As pointed by @WeatherVane in comment, you need to provide the correct conversion specifier to the corresponding argument or the behavior of your program will be undefined:

**C99 7.19.6.1 p 9 (`fprintf`)**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.248) If **any argument** is **not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification**, the behavior is undefined.

For `printf()` the argument `rate` should have a conversion specifier `%f`:

```
printf("After %i number of years, the deposit in the savings account is now %f", x, rate);
```

**C99 7.19.6.1 p 8** (`fprintf`)

> `f`,F A **`double` argument** representing a floating-point number

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. Appreciated